# Android firebase push notification for two different database path

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-functions

I am completely new to JavaScript and also Firebase, I am trying to get a push notification when the data is changed in the Firebase real-time database, I am able to get specific tree child notice but not the other.

the database structure is like

```
calendar-->{new data}
|
users-->Notices-->year-->{new data}
```

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref("users/Notices/{Year}/{notification_time}/notice").onWrite((snapshot, context) => {
  const notification_id = context.params.notification_time;
  const Year = context.params.Year;
  var valueObject = snapshot.after.val();
  console.log("year:" + Year + "|notification:" + notification_id);
  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: "Notice for " + Year,
      body: snapshot.after.val(),
      sound: "default",
      click_action: "Notices"
    },
    data: {
      title: Year,
      message: "recieved a notice"
    }
  };
  return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("notifications", payload, options);
});
```

The above snippet is good for getting the notices child update, but I need to get notified for the change in calendar child also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to do something like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref("users/Notices/{Year}/{notification_time}/notice").onWrite((snapshot, context) => {
  const notification_id = context.params.notification_time;
  const Year = context.params.Year;
  var valueObject = snapshot.after.val();
  return sendNotification(valueObject, Year)
});
exports.sendNotification2 = functions.database.ref("calendar").onWrite((snapshot, context) => {
  var valueObject = snapshot.after.val();
  return sendNotification(valueObject.message, valueObject.year)
});
function sendNotification(body, Year){
  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: "Notice for " + Year,
      body: body,
      sound: "default",
      click_action: "Notices"
    },
    data: {
      title: Year,
      message: "recieved a notice"
    }
  };
  return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("notifications", payload);
}
```